# How to get google refresh token and access token from access token using node js

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

How can i use access token to get new refresh token after google authentication. I need refresh token for creating an event. But docs says that we won't get refresh token every time when user authenticate with his email id.

I tried to get both access token and refresh token from google code. But it is not giving "invalid grant_type" error.

Is there any way to get refresh token from using

- Authenticated code or
- access token which we will get with the code

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I need to check after my app is verified.